# How I add the word Print instead of the URL using mla-format bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, mla-style

I need to create my workscite page reference, but my English professor is asking to put at the end of each bibliography reference the word print for all my book bibliography according to MLA ed 7th

Im using bibdesk as a Bibliography manager and Im using this is file `mla-new.bst` to format my bibliography as MLA, but I cannot find how to add the "Print." string at the end of each bibliography output.

my code is

```
\doublelespacing
\begin{document}

\begin{mla}{First Name}{Last Name}{Professor's Name}{ English 1302}{28 March 2011}{Research Paper}

\bibliographystyle{mla-good} 
\doublespacing

\citeauthor{Sizemore:1977rr,Powell:2008cr,Gross:1990wd,Kempf:1994nx,Struc:1986eu,Sharkey:2006oq,Wagner:2006qe,Fleissner:1985kl,Morris:2009ai,Gray:1962tg,Yelin:2010dp,De-La-Durantaye:2007hc,Clarke:2009sp,Gans:1998ij,Spurr:2011th,Parkison:2008bs,Howe:1949fy,Robert:1977fv,Swales:1981la,Krause:2005qy}}
%\begin{mlaquote}\end{mlaquote} \begin{workscited}
%\vspace{-3cm}

\begin{workscited}
%\vspace{-3cm}
\bibliography{bubus}{} 
\end{workscited} 
%\citeauthor{Literature}
%\citeauthor{Marias}
% (\citeauthor{Marias}).  % cs(\citeauthor{Rozin} 245).  \citeauthor{Fonseca} 245). \citeauthor{Highmore}  \citeauthor{Locher} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).